# Binding to Elements of Arrays in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, data-binding

In AngularJS, I can successfully bind text inputs to elements of arrays:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="foo[2]" />
```

Is this allowed, or does it just work by accident?

When I try to bind `select` elements or checkbox input to array elements they fail to work - i.e. the `select` element does not change the displayed, or bound, value on selection and the checkbox does not display a tick when clicked.

Am I missing something here?

---

Update: It works in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/azFzc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does work on select elements

Look this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fStE7/

HTML

```
<div ng-app>
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    Select
<select ng-change="changed()" 
        ng-options="option.value as option.label for option in options" ng-model="ar[0]">
 </select>
</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function MyController($scope){
    $scope.options = [
        { label : "first element", value : 0 },
        { label : "second element", value : 1 },
    ]

    $scope.ar = [];
    $scope.ar[0] = 0;

    $scope.changed = function(){
         console.log($scope.ar[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it was a bug in my app, not in my understanding of AngularJS.

Answer (score 1):

I modified the above example to show non numeric array assignment through binding.  Which is most useful when dealing with more complex data or when your array uses a key system for updating and retrieving values.

https://jsfiddle.net/9obtkoa7/

HTML

```
<div ng-app>
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    Select
<select ng-change="changed()" 
        ng-options="option.value as option.label for option in options" ng-model="ar['SomeId']">
 </select>
</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function MyController($scope){
    $scope.options = [
        { label : "first element", value : '1' },
        { label : "second element", value : '2' },
    ]

    $scope.ar = [];
    $scope.ar['SomeId'] = '1';

    $scope.changed = function(){
         console.log($scope.ar['SomeId']);
    }
}
```